# matrix multiplication involving squaring entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, matlab, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix equations (all entries are in general complex):

$\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\\w_{0}\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}v_{2}\\w_{2}\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}V_{2}\\W_{2}\end{pmatrix}=B\begin{pmatrix}V_{3}\\W_{3}\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}v_{3}\\w_{3}\end{pmatrix}=C\begin{pmatrix}v_{4}\\w_{4}\end{pmatrix}$

where $V_{i}=|v_{i}|^2$, $W_{i}=|w_{i}|^2$, and the capital letters stand for `2x2` matrices. I want to get something like

$\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\\w_{0}\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}v_{3}\\w_{3}\end{pmatrix}$

What is the best way to do this? Ideally I want the method to be easily implementable in Python or Matlab.

Thanks

Comment: Under some assumptions on $A,B,C$ such as invertibility, then $(C(B(Ax)^2)^2)=y$ can be solved as follows: First you solve $Cu =y$, then $Bv=u^{1/2}$ and finally $Ax=v^{1/2}$. Then you get $(C(B(Ax)^2)^2)=(C(Bv)^2)=Cu=y$. (exponents are taken component wise)

Answer (score 0):

Impossible.  Your equations don't allow you to determine $v_0$ and $w_0$ from 
$v_3$ and $w_3$.  You could multiply $v_0$, $w_0$, $v_2$ and $w_2$ by $-1$ and the equations would still remain true.